# Woher kommt die Redewendung "jemandem geht ein Licht auf"?

Tags: etymology, phrase

Woher kommt die Redewendung, jemandem gehe ein Licht auf, wenn er plötzliches Verständnis erlangt?

Gefunden habe ich nur [einen Zeitungsartikel](https://www.shz.de/lokales/norddeutsche-rundschau/woher-kommt-die-redewendung-mir-geht-ein-licht-auf-id150785.html), der das mit Matthäus 4.16 in Verbindung bringt:

> [D]as Volk, das in Finsternis saß, hat ein großes Licht gesehen; und die da saßen am Ort und Schatten des Todes, denen ist ein Licht aufgegangen.

Das scheint aber bestenfalls für die Etablierung der grammatischen Konstruktion verantwortlich sein zu können. Wenn man den Artikel weiter liest, stellt man auch fest, dass seine Intention seelsorgerischer und nicht philologischer Art ist.

Answer (score 3):

Mein Brockhaus von 2003 bestätigt dein Bibelzitat, führt aber auch andere Bibelstellen an:

> **Es geht mir ein Licht auf**
>
> Diese Redensart geht auf verschiedene
>   Bibelstellen zurück, z.B. **Hiob 25,3** und **Psalm 97,11**. Im Neuen
>   Testament (**Matthäus 4,16**) heißt es: »...das Volk, das in der
>   Finsternis saß, hat ein großes Licht gesehen; und die da saßen am Ort
>   und Schatten des Todes, denen ist ein Licht aufgegangen.« Im
>   Unterschied zum bildlichen Gebrauch in der Bibel, der die Erhellung
>   des menschlichen Geistes durch das Licht des Glaubens meint, wird mit
>   dem Zitat heute ausgedrückt, dass man plötzlich etwas versteht oder
>   durchschaut, was einem zunächst völlig unklar war. Auch scherzhafte
>   Abwandlungen sind üblich geworden, wie z.B. »Es geht mir ein
>   Kronleuchter auf«.

[Hiob 25,3:](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/ELB/Hiob25%2C3)

> Gibt es eine Zahl für seine Scharen? Und über wem erhebt sich nicht
>   sein Licht?

[Psalm 97,11:](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/ELB/Psalm97%2C11)

> Licht ist dem Gerechten gesät und Freude den von Herzen Aufrichtigen.

Comment: In Cartoons sieht man das ja auch: eine brennende Glühbirne erscheint über dem Kopf desjenigen, dem ein Licht aufgeht. Das ist anscheinend international.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, das war, was mich auf die Frage gebracht hat: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75324/where-and-when-does-the-idea-light-bulb-appear-for-the-first-time Trotzdem ist mir im Englischen keine entsprechende Redewendung bekannt.

Comment: @CarstenS Im Englischen gibt es immerhin "It dawns on me.", was aber eher dem im deutschen ja ebenfalls gebräuchlichen "Es dämmert mir" entspricht und das ich immer als eher graduellen, weniger plötzlichen Prozess verstehe (eben das Bild von (Morgen-)Dämmerung vs. Aufgang).

Comment: Englische Bibelübersetzungen verwenden für Matthäus 4,16 verschiedene Formulierungen "...a light has come upon those...", "...a light has dawned..." oder auch mit größerer impliziter Geschwindigkeit "...a light has sprung up...".

Comment: In vielen Sprachen hat *Helligkeit* etwas mit "Verständnis" zu tun - ("bright guy", "der ist aber helle", "na, klar", "clarus", "lucide", "claire",....) Das ist so universell, dass ich nicht an das Bibelzitat glaube.

Answer (score 1):

Die Wendung *Licht aufgehen* wird bereits von [Adelung, 1793](http://www.zeno.org/Adelung-1793/K/adelung-1793-01-0494) so aufgeführt. Dass das Erlangen von zusätzlichem Verständnis mit dem *Erleuchten*, also dem Fördern des Sinnes mit der größten Übertragungskapazität, gleichgesetzt wird, erscheint mir derart naheliegend, dass ich nicht an eine einzelne dokumentierbare Erklärungskette glaube, ich lasse mich aber gerne eines Besseren belehren. Der Verweis auf das Bibelzitat stützt die These dass die Gleichsetzung ziemlich universell ist (und daher hier off topic?).